# Is there a fast way to unlock Torment mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

How do you unlock Torment? DO I just need to beat Malthael? So if I join someones game before the last boss can I just fight him and unlock it.

Comment: Level 60, according to the tips.

Comment: If you jump in someones story game and beat Malthael you will **unlock Adventure Mode**. There is no need to complete all of Act V

Comment: You should also try to unlock it either in the current season or in non-seasonal mode, because the next season is just about to start and players will be far more willing (and able) in pushing your character when they are more powerful themselves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need one of your characters reach Level 60 to unlock Torment difficulty.

[Here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty)'s the game guide.

Answer (score 4):

> *How do you unlock Torment?*

If you reach level 60 with one of your character you unlock Torment difficulty. See here:
[Game Guide - Diablo III](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-difficulty)

> You’ll unlock Master difficulty when any of your characters completes
>   the game, and **Torment difficulty when any of your characters reaches
>   level 60**.
>
> *Is there a fast way to unlock Torment mode?*

Yeah, fast leveling! Ask a friend or ingame, if he can help you leveling. Make a game on highest difficulty and let your friend kill everything. If you killed Malthael you unlock Adventure Mode. Do Bounties on highest difficulty and earn even more experience.

Comment: If the person without torment makes the game, it will obviously be restricted to hard or master. Will the following work instead? If you have two friends, one makes a torment 6 level 1 game, whilst the other joins it on a level 70. You then join this game, so you can get to level 60 and unlock it yourself even faster. Or is it not possible to join a friends torment game if you haven't unlocked it yourself? Maybe you can do this with only one friend, they make torment 6 level 1, you join, they leave and rejoin on their level 70.